# Easily print current package version in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a node.js project to run on browser, so I have a Makefile with a few tasks that bundle everything in a single file (with [browserify](http://browserify.org/)) and then minify it ([uglify-js](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2)). I decided to use a Makefile instead of Grunt or others because it's simple and solve my problem.

The generated files are `mylib.js` and `mylib.min.js`, but I want something like `mylib.1.0.1.js`, where the version comes from my `package.json`.

I need a npm command to tell me what version is described inside package.json, but I didn't
found any on the docs. Anyone knows how to get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
node -e 'console.log(require("./package").version)'
```

or

```
npm --loglevel error list mylib | head -1 | cut -d " " -f 1 | cut -d @ -f 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to grab the version of a dependency, the command:

```
npm list | grep 'mylib' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d @ -f 2
```

will return the string "1.0.1"

**EDIT** based on [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199781/easily-print-current-package-version-in-node-js#answer-17199908), it seems that this would do also:

```
node -e 'console.log(require("./package.json").dependencies.mylib)'
```

Comment: As I read the question, he want's his own package's version, which he is calling `mylib`.